# Show hide div containing gridview between postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi I am new to using jquery , I am having a doubt how to implement this scenario :-

I have div element which should be initially hidden on the page load, whenever I click a button which is going to do a postback and populate the grid present inside the div , then the div should become visible after the postback.

```
<asp:button ID="btngetgrid" runat="server" OnClick="btngetgrid_Click">

<div id="mydiv" runat="server">
<asp:gridview runat="server" Id="grddisplay"/>
</div>
```

On .cs file

```
protected void btngetgrid_click()
{
 code to populate grid
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are anyways going to do a full page postback then you can simply use the `Visible` property of `Div` like this:-

```
<div id="mydiv" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" Id="grddisplay"/>
</div>
```

Then, in code behind if you get the data from data source then set the `Visible` property to true:-

```
protected void btngetgrid_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    //code to populate grid
    if(records count > 0)
    {
        mydiv.Visible = true;
    } 
}
```

If you are doing partial postback using ajax, then you can do it with jQuery otherwise in your full postback case it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Code below will resolve your problem:

```js
$("#btngetgrid").click(function(){
  var mydiv = $("#mydiv");
  if(!mydiv.is(":visible")) {
    mydiv.fadeIn();
  }
  
  // Here you can call the function to populate the grid
  
});
```

```css
#mydiv { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="btngetgrid">Button</a>

<div id="mydiv" runat="server">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Comment: but where do I populate the grid if I use the button this way ?, I have a button that does the work of populating the grid on codebehind, plus the button click induces postback

Comment: You can call function to populate data inside the "#btngetgrid" click function.